# Type mismatch error in Calculate Field tool in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, error

I'm trying to run a rather lengthy model (built in ArcGIS 9.3.1) in ArcGIS 10.1 and I'm recieving an error on a Calculate Field tool. The error is - `Type mismatch: 'iif'`.

This error is refering to an expression in the tool: `iif(IsNull( [PID] ) ,NA,[PID])`.

[image]

I tried "if" instead of "iif" but then recieved a generic error.

I never had this issue when running the model in 9.3.1. I'm not sure what to do here.  Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try quoting NA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `iif` directly in field calculator expressions, you need to use the code block. There are some examples on the [Field Calculator Examples help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004s000000).

**Python:**

```
Expression:
Reclass(!WELL_YIELD!)

Expression Type:
PYTHON_9.3

Code Block:
def Reclass(WellYield):
    if (WellYield >= 0 and WellYield <= 10):
        return 1
    elif (WellYield > 10 and WellYield <= 20):
        return 2
    elif (WellYield > 20 and WellYield <= 30):
        return 3
    elif (WellYield > 30):
        return 4
```

**VBA:**

```
Expression:
density

Expression Type:
VB

Code Block:
Dim density
If [POP90_SQMI] < 100 Then
density = "low"

elseif [POP90_SQMI] < 300 Then
density = "medium"

else
density = "high"
end if
```

Comment: That would be VBScript, not VBA. VBA was removed from the Field Calculator at 10. IIF is a VBA function. The reason it's not working at 10.1 is that it doesn't exist in VBScript. Otherwise this is a good answer.

Comment: Thank's guys.  For dummies like me, how would you go about writing the code block.  Sorry for being such a vampire, I don't know much about coding.

Comment: This worked, thanks dmahr.  And thanks to nmpeterson for spoon feeding me the code block.

Answer (score 2):

As dmahr said, you have to use a codeblock. In your case, that would be something like this, using Python:

```
def null_to_NA(field):
    if field == None:
        return 'NA'
    else:
        return field
```

And then the expression would be:

```
null_to_NA(!PID!)
```